# Python workflow for testing modules without re-executing the entire codebase

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

I'm working on a python project that spans across multiple files and directories. Here's my workflow:

1. Run main python script
2. Main script calls some functions in other files
3. Functions in other files/directories execute
4. In the middle of execution, there is a bug in one of the functions, but I find the bug only after the main script finishes. Sometimes, there may not be a bug, but rather some parameter that needs tweaking.
5. I go back and fix the bug/make the necessary tweaks and re-run the main program and this time it executes fine.

Obviously, this workflow is terribly inefficient as considerable amount of code (that runs prior to the buggy function) gets re-executed. What would be ideal is to run the program in ipython and after discovering the issue and making the necessary changes, restart from the place where the buggy function executions starts and not from the beginning. I'm not sure how to achieve this and any help would be much appreciated.

I know how to rerun lines from ipython history (%rerun) and how to ensure autoreload of changed files in ipython, but in this case, I can't really type out the lines of code into ipython. Writing unit tests may not always be feasible, so I need an alternate solution. My use case is something similar to setting a "breakpoint" and then re-executing code past the breakpoint multiple times so as to avoid re-executing the code prior to the breakpoint more than once, while ensuring that all the necessary variables (until that stage) are correctly populated. One final condition is that I may not be able to use an IDE and vim is the only editor available across all the environments I work with.

Answer (score 0):

You could start writing test cases for every function and try to debug each function separately instead of the whole program/script.

There is a python unittest-module: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html and a lot of tutorials like (just an example): http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/tests/

It seems annoying writing tests but thinking about test cases gives deeper understanding of "How should the function behave if...".

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, unit testing is not possible given how complex the codebase is. Additionally, most of my use cases involve parameter tweaking rather than bug fixing. Writing unit tests would not help there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code module to include "breakpoints" in your code

```
import code
# ... later in your program add
code.interact(local=locals()) # enter python interpreter at this point (ctrl+D to continue execution)
```